# Remove specific administrator's capability

Tags: plugins, admin, users, user-roles, capabilities

I've created two administrator users X and Y. And now I need to remove capability of 'edit_plugins' from user Y.

I've searched and found, http://goo.gl/LttuvX

```
$user = new WP_User( 'Y' );
$user->remove_cap('edit_plugins');
```

But it is not working please let me know how to do it.

Previously I've created new role with same capability as administrator, but in plugins we create menus like `add_menu_page(..,capability => 'administrator',..);` so new role fails to access plugin pages.

Comment: The new role method will work, just feed your `add_XXX_page` calls to use a capability instead of a role, eg. `manage_options`.

Comment: Could you specify it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically deny a capability from a user (not a role), you need to use the [`add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/) method and specify that the `$grant` parameter is false.

```
$user = new WP_User( 'Y' );
$user->add_cap( 'edit_plugins', false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by replacing the user@email.com

```
add_action('init', 'remove_specific_admin_cap');
function remove_specific_admin_cap(){
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if( $user && isset($user->user_email) && 'user@email.com' == $user->user_email ) {
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_plugins' );

    }
}
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_cap

Comment: your solution restricting all administrators. So I added, 
`else{
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'edit_plugins' );
}` it works but I need to refresh page twice.

Answer (score 0):

Direct editing of Themes/Plugins should never be enabled and is a huge security risk. Any editing you do should be done locally.

You can disable it by adding `define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);` to your `wp-config.php` file.

If you do not want them messing with plugins, then `remove_cap( 'install_plugins' );` or `remove_cap( 'activate_plugins' );`